# Using sed to replace a character before another character in a line

Tags: shell-script

I try to use sed or whatever to replace a number of a line /opt/tin/toss to become a *

For example

```
37 7 * * * /opt/tin/toss
43 7 * * * /opt/tin/te1
58 7 * * * /opt/tin/test2
```

Output:

```
37 * * * * /opt/tin/toss
43 7 * * * /opt/tin/te1
58 7 * * * /opt/tin/test2
```

Normally, 7 generates randomly, It can be 2, 4 or 8, running from 0-24.

Comment: Replace whole line using sed.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. I guess you want to modify the line that contains `/opt/tin/toss`. What change do you want to make? Do you want to change the second field, the second number, the third digit, or what? What do you mean by "7 generates randomly, It can be 2, 4 or 8, running from 0-24"?

Comment: yes, I want to modify the line contains /opt/tin/toss. Number 7 is not static number. Sometimes it changes to 8 or 12... I want to change 7 to *

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/\/opt\/tin\/toss/ s/^\([^ ]* \+\)[^ ]*\( .*\)$/\1*\2/'
```

You'd read this as,

Where there is `/opt/tin/toss`, substitute the pattern that matches

`^` starting of line followed by

`\([^ ]* \+\)`

first group `\(` of `[^ ]*` any number characters until one or more spaces `\+`, and closing of group `\)`

`[^ ]*`

followed by `[^ ]*` anything until space

`\( .*\)`

followed by second group `\( .*\)$` matching space followed by anything until end

with

`/\1*\2/`

first group followed by `*` followed by second group.

Answer (score -1):

A example of sed that will so

```
sed  's/^\([0-9]*\) [0-9]*  *\(\*  *\* *\*  *\/opt\/tin\/toss.*\)$/\1 * \2/'
```

this `\([0-9]*\)` will match for the first digit an keep the value in `\1`

this `\(\*  *\* *\*  *\/opt\/tin\/toss.*\)`will match for the last 3 stars ond the command line , and  keep the value in `\1`

Comment: This assumes there are `*` at every other location where there is /opt/tin/toss, would not work in case of `37-39/2 7 2 * * /opt/tin/toss`